# Illegal unit of measure from `\node`

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have the following tikz commands

```
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node at (3.2,0) {$\mathbb{R}$};
            \node at (-.2,-.25) {$I$};
            \draw (-3,0) --(3,0);

            \node at (-1.3,2) {$U$};

            \node at (2.2,1.6) {$^+U$};
            \draw plot[smooth] coordinates
                {(1,0)(2,1)(0,3)(-2,0)};

            \node at (2.2,-1.6) {$^-U$};
            \draw plot[smooth] coordinates
                {(1,0)(2,-1)(0,-3)(-2,0)};

            \node at (.3.4,1.5) {$z$};
            \node at (.3,1.5) {\textbullet};
            \draw[dashed] (.3,0) -- (.3,1.5);

            \node at (.3.4,-1.5) {$\conj{z}$};
            \node at (.3,-1.5) {\textbullet};
            \draw[dashed] (.3,0) -- (.3,-1.5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

When I try to compile it, the console says `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).` at the lines `\node at (.3.4,-1.5)`. Other lines seem to have no problem. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first dot in the coordinate is wrong … it should be

```
 \node at (3.4,1.5) {$z$};
```

or maybe

```
\node at (.3,1.5) {$z$};
```